# This word chain will come back to me

Tags: word, word-ladder

I am a four-letter word.

> My anagram's antonym's Rot(13)'s synonym's homophone is a portion of
> me.

What word am I?

Note: There are six separate words in this chain. Please list them all with explanation. I used popular sites like [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/) or [Wordhippo.com](https://www.wordhippo.com/).

[image]

Hint

> There are not many words that transform to another word after Rot13. The Rot13 word is a 3 letter word.

Hint 2

> This word is typically described by two separate colors

Hint 3

> One of the six words in my solution is Stake

Comment: (You say there's not many, but I've been working off [this list of 75 options](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67165) since this was posted and still haven't found the 'in' yet...! I daresay this list probably isn't even exhaustive...)

Comment: More added to the Hint

Comment: Thanks, that will probably help get a foothold. Unfortunately the list I linked contains almost no eligible candidates now - d'oh!

Comment: Here are some not-too-obscure ones. ant/nag, bar/one, fur/she, gel/try, vex/irk

Comment: On the right track @LukasRotter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the third hint, it is now possible to see a cycle using:

> **MEAT**
>
>  MEAT
>  <sub>is an anagram of</sub>
>  TEAM
>  <sub>is an antonym of</sub>
>  ONE
>  <sub>rot-13's to</sub>
>  BAR
>  <sub>is a [synonym](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/stake.html) of</sub>
>  STAKE
>  <sub>is a homophone of</sub>
>  STEAK
>  <sub>is a portion of</sub>
>  MEAT
>
>  Re an earlier [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/this-word-chain-will-come-back-to-me/110478#comment310308_110438) of mine on another answer, this interpretation makes linguistic sense of the OP's use of the word 'portion' rather than 'substring'.

Re Hint 2, the 'two colours' referred to are:

> [**red**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_meat) and [**white**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_meat) meat.

Comment: Nice one! Is there a way to get a *notification*, or *follow* a question, so one can know when there's activity on a given question, or at least when it's modified?

Comment: @Kabir Indeed - [as of last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) you can click 'Follow' where you see 'Share Edit Follow Flag' (or some subset of those depending on your current privileges) at the bottom of the question or answer :)

Comment: "Portion"? Isn't Steak a type of (answer) itself?

Comment: In many places it is defined as "a thick slice" or "a portion" of meat @Sid

Answer (score 8):

I have a possible answer:

> [image: SOLS is an anagram of LOSS which is an antonym of BAR which is a ROT13 of ONE which is a synonym of SOLE which is a homophone of SOL which is a portion of SOLS]

While *is a portion of*, *anagram*, and *ROT-13* are self-explanatory, the sources for the other three transformations are linked below:

> [Antonym of BAR](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bar)
>  [Synonym of ONE](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/one)
>  [Homophones of SOLE](https://www.homophone.com/search?type=&q=sole)

Note:

> `LOSS` is listed as the antonym of `BAR`, this solution assumes that this relationship is commutative.

Comment: If this is the intended interpretation of 'is a portion of', I am surprised the word 'substring' was not used in place of 'portion'...

Comment: Oh, so you mean, we should actually be allowed to use the letters in any order and position?

Comment: No, no - I was unsure exactly how to interpret 'portion' (I didn't find it as obvious a word as you did, it seems!), and was really leaving it to the end to see if I could back-interpret the OP's intention. If anything I was erring on it being more of a linguistic thing depending on the *meaning* of the words e.g. SLICE is a portion of CAKE, CHAPTER is a portion of a BOOK. But if you've interpreted it correctly I was just querying the puzzle's vocab choice. If anything I would say rearranging the letters would definitely *not* be an acceptable use :) (that's just an anagram of sorts)

Comment: Aah, now I get you. Actually, that does sound like a promising tangent too! Maybe it is what the OP intended, but somehow I never thought of it that way.

Comment: I don't really understand that alleged antonym relationship, whatever thesaurus.com may say. Can anyone explain to me what they might have in mind?

Comment: @Stiv's comments are kind of applicable with my answer. I was thinking similarly. However your interpretation is creative. +1

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll throw my imperfect guess into the ring

> MEAL
>  MALE (Anagram of meal)
>  SHE  (Antonym of male)
>  FUR  (Rot13 of she)
>  MANE (synonym of fur.  I'd have preferred coarse, but that doesn't seem to show up as a synonym)
>  MAIN (homonym of MANE and the MAIN course is a portion of a MEAL)

Comment: This is pretty good! Not entirely sure about the last line but the rest is fairly convincing.

Comment: I tried to get this to work but didn't think of rot13(ZNAR). Not sure it's quite a synonym, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yeah, it doesn't immediately spring to mind, but I found it on his wordhippo site listed as a synonym way too late last night.  Then went to sleep thinking of rot13(n zvffvbanel jnagvat gb crg n yvba'f pbnefr znar naq orpbzvat gur znva pbhefr)

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this terribly satisfactory, but it does kinda meet all the conditions.

> PEON (i.e., a person with a junior position in some hierarchy)

has an anagram

> OPEN (of, e.g., a door)

which has an antonym

> BAR (i.e., block passage)

which ROT13s to

> ONE (adj., as in "the one and only ...")

which has a synonym

> SOLE (i.e., only)

which has a homonym

> SOUL (i.e., alleged immaterial part of a person's being)

which is a part of

> any person (if there are such things as souls at all), including in particular a PEON.

The last step is the least satisfactory one for me; the others all seem pretty good.

Comment: Creative. Like you said all other steps are good. I wonder if we put a GENERIC question out there about any six different word changes (like the ones in the puzzle plus others like gramagrams) how many great answers we will get. No limit on the starting word. Just a thought.

Comment: I had already been thinking along the lines I suspect you are trying to hint at, but so far haven't been able to find good candidates for the last two words. But I'll think about it some more...

Comment: ... though, actually, the thing I am interpreting as a hint seems not so likely to be hinting at what I thought it was hinting at, in view of the rest of the sentence. Hmm.

Comment: This comment is a puzzle in itself...

Comment: Heh. So, I thought it was curious that DrD emphasized the word GENERIC like that, and thought it might be hinting at the word ANY, which is a part of MANY both lexically and semantically; and MANY is an antonym of ONE which rot13s to BAR. But I can't get the pieces to line up properly. E.g., if I start with MYNA then I can anagram to MANY, antonym to ONE, rot13 to BAR, but I haven't found a homonym of a synonym of BAR that is a part of a MYNA or any other bird. Or we can start with MANY, preceded by its part ANY, anagram to MYNA ... but then finding a 3-letter synonym is tough.

Comment: And the thing that makes me not so sure that that's what DrD had in mind is the fact that elsewhere in that sentence the literal word "any" appears, which I would not expect from someone going out of their way to hint _indirectly_ at that word.

Comment: But it still seems likely to me that DrD's comment was intended as a hint, and that I'm looking for a starting word hinted at by "GENERIC" and "no limit". Best I've found so far are SOME and EACH but SOME doesn't seem to have any usable anagrams and EACH has only ACHE which seems unhelpful.

Comment: Okay, now I get you, haha. I personally don't feel that was a hint. I think he really just meant what he said literally. Time will tell.