# Longest "Cycle" word chain

Tags: word, word-property, open-ended

Linked to [This word chain will come back to me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/this-word-chain-will-come-back-to-me).

That puzzle got some very creative answers and comments. Although the puzzle itself took some work, I found it very interesting.

So here is a more general puzzle.

What is the longest word chain/cycle can you create that is a full cycle as shown below for 6 words using the following word transitions in ANY order:

1   Anagram

2  Antonym

3  Synonym

4  Homophone/nym

5  Rhyme Word

6  Rot 13

7  Translate: French or German or Spanish  only one time All other words must be English

8   Gramagrams

9   "Is a part/substring of" or "Is a portion of"   see the link for example

**Rules**

All words must be separate words from Merriam Webstar dictionary (except the translation words of course)

You cannot use the same type of transition twice

You do not have to use all the 9 listed transitions

Since 6 words cycle is already done, there is a minimum of 7 words.

If you use translation then the next word in cycle must be english.

Synonyms and Antonyms can come from Thesaurus.com or Wordhippo.com

I do understand that this is a bit open ended puzzle but hope the Community will allow it. If not I am "open" to "closing" it (antonym of open!)

[image]

Comment: Are abbreviations allowed?

Comment: Sure. If it really makes it interesting!

Comment: What does this mean? *Since 6 words cycle is already done, there is a minimum of 7 words.*

Comment: Need a 7 word or more cycle @KabirKanhaArora all separate words all different transitions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019. (As the tag says)

Answer (score 4):

(9 words) Not terribly satisfactory, but I think it should be valid.

> Nye as in [the county](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nye_County,_Nevada), [NV](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/NV) as the abbreviation for Nevada, and the mildly dodgy abroad/nigh antonym [according to WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/nigh.html)
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have made a cycle with 8 words:

> [image]

Comment: Hmmm... It feels a bit of a stretch to me to say that Nagging and Jarring really *rhyme* (Nagging and Tagging, yes)... And ants and mites are really distinct creatures, so I'm not sure they're truly synonymous... I like the German section though - that part's very satisfactory :)

Comment: I agree, I'll take a fresh stab at it tomorrow and try to come up with a better cycle.